# Difference dates: total days

Tags: objective-c

```
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:dateBegin
                                              toDate:dateEnd options:0];
totalDays = [components day];
```

That not gives me the total days between the 2 dates but simple the difference between the 2 days of the 2 dates. it dateBegin is 8 sep 2012 and dateEnd is 10 nov 2012 the result is 2! Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your bellow line

> NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

to

> NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;

Comment: Thanks, and i've also found another solution.

Comment: BTW: the Code-Example "DateDiff" which comes with Xcode is also inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDateComponents *components;
    NSInteger days;

    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSDayCalendarUnit 
    fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0];
    days = [components day];
```

I've found that solution too.